# Push and pull Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Первый раз столкнулся с бутстрапом 3, появился проблема. Нужно чтобы на sm разрешениях 1 и 3 блок менялись местами. Проблема в том, что они меняются даже на lg разрешениях, хотя пишу col-sm-push. Что делаю, не так ?( Прикрепляю пример https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/qjKqBL

```css
.item
  color: yellow
  text-align: center
.c
  background-color: red
.q
  background-color: navy
.r
  background-color: #000
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-push-8">
      <div class="item c">
        123
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="item q">
        123444
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-pull-8">
      <div class="item r">
        123555
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS без фигурных скобок — это SASS или что?

Comment: Совершенно верно, SASS )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте соответствующие `col-md-push-0` и `col-md-pull-0`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-push-0"><div class="item c">
      123
      </div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><div class="item q">
      123444
      </div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8 col-md-pull-0"><div class="item r">
      123555
      </div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[ПРИМЕР](https://codepen.io/igolka97/pen/BZVprP)**

Не знаю, может это костыль, но без всяких допиливаний исходников бутстрапа -  работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.

Comment: @DenisDenis так отметьте мой вопрос как решение тогда)